# How to set CloudWatch Settings for AWS APIGateway Stage

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

in AWS ApiGateway, after using the JAVA api to deploy a new stage, how can I enable the CloudWatch Settings with Java API rather than through aws console?

For the [create-stage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/create-stage.html), I can get the CloudWatch settings in the `MethodSetting` under the `CreateStage` output, but I cannot set the settings when I create the stage or create deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to update the CloudWatch settings for your stage with a [patch request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-stage.html) to the [update-stage operation](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-api-gateway/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/apigateway/model/UpdateStageRequest.java#L168)

Here's a sample code snippet (I haven't actually tested this; but the basic principal should work):

```
AmazonApiGateway apiGateway = ...;
UpdateStageRequest req = new UpdateStageRequest().withRestApiId(<api-id>).
            withStageName(<stage-name>).
            withPatchOperations(
                new PatchOperation().withPath("*/*/metrics/enabled")
                                    .withOp("replace")
                                    .withValue("true"));

apiGateway.upate(req);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but why aws prefer to use patch operation rather than other more obvious api